# Value at risk of normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, finance

> The value at risk of a random variable $X$ is defined as $$VaR_a(X)=\inf\{l\in\mathbb{R}|P(X>l)\leq 1-a\}$$ If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, I want to show that $$VaR_a(X)=\mu+\Phi^{-1}(1-a)\sigma$$

If I start calculating $P(X>l)$, then $P(X>l)=1-\Phi(\frac{l-\mu}{\sigma})$ and thus, $P(X>l)\leq 1-a$ is equivalent to $\Phi(\frac{l-\mu}{\sigma})\geq a$, which is equivalent to $l\geq \Phi^{-1}(a)\sigma+\mu$ and $VaR_a(X)=\Phi^{-1}(a)\sigma+\mu$.

So why do i get $\Phi^{-1}(a)$ instead of $\Phi^{-1}(1-a)$?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $VaR_a(\cdot)$ - should the $l$ instead be $x$?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, of course.

Comment: By $\phi$ do you mean the distribution function of $Z$, where $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$? Generally one denotes the density of the standard normal distribution by $\phi$ and the CDF by $\Phi$ so it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Math1000 Thought that my symbol is the same as the symbol outlined by you.

Comment: The value at risk $v$ of a random variable $X$ at the confidence level $\alpha$ is [often defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_at_risk) $$v=\inf\{x\mid P(X+x<0)\leqslant1-\alpha\}$$ If $X$ is continuous with CDF $F_X$, this yields $$F_X(-v)=1-\alpha$$ hence $$v=-F_X^{-1}(1-\alpha)$$
If $X$ is normal $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $X=\mu+\sigma Z$ with $Z$ standard normal hence $$1-\alpha=P(X+v<0)=P(\sigma Z<-v-\mu)=\Phi(-(v+\mu)/\sigma)$$ that is, $$v=-\mu-\sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)$$ It seems the formula you are trying to prove is ...

Comment: ... rather based on a different definition of the value at risk, namely, $$v=\sup\{x\mid P(X<x)\leqslant1-\alpha\}$$